# Turn off Linux file cache

Tags: linux, cache

How do I turn off write cache in Linux? More specifically, SUSE 11?

My problem is that heavy I/O kills the system even if the generating process is a user priority class, and the starved processes are RR/RT class. So my high availability system breaks with lots of timeouts.

I have `/` mounted on a flash drive, and a few mount points looking into a RAID controller. For the RAID, I want to try to turn the cache off, since it has a cache inside. But if it needs to be system-wide, fine.

So far I used `sync` option to `mount`, but it's not quite like turning off the cache.

Any ideas?

Comment: General rule to be real-time is not to mix the workloads, especially batch and interactive tasks. If you want a service to be real-time, then put it on a dedicated server. Otherwise, it would be interesting to hear if ionice suggested below would help alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When mounting your hard drives use `-o sync` which will turn off write buffering for the drive.

You can also set it up in your fstab:

```
/dev/sda1    /    reiserfs        sync    0   0
```

Comment: The OP says he already tried this.

Comment: yes, that's actually how you turn off file write caching. When I was asking the question I didn't know enough to ask correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For a plain hard disk it would normally be

```
hdparm -W 0 /dev/sdX
```

but RAID controllers typically don't pass that through.

You'll have to check the configuration interface of your RAID controller for any options.  It might not be possible.

Comment: hdparm affects the block device. Linux cache is much higher up

Comment: I suppose it depends on which "write cache" he means.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [drop_caches](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_drop_caches.html) can help you. It does not seem to disable the cache, merely clear it.

Comment: What's wrong with `sync`?

Answer (score 0):

please have a look here: https://superuser.com/a/464382/106740
With http://code.google.com/p/pagecache-mangagement/, you can disable file caches on a per-application level