# Disable Linux Page Cache for Reads

Tags: linux, cache, postgresql, hard-drive-cache

Is there a  way to turn-off page caching for reads in Linux? More specifically, I would like my processes to read directly from the disk.

The setting of my problem: I am trying out new query processing techniques in Postgres and measuring their running time. To have an accurate comparison of the running time of different methods, I need to turn-off reading from OS cache.

I have read the following approaches but none of them apply to my case:

1. Clear the cache using `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`: I need to call this at every iteration of my query which would mess up my final measured times.
2. Use `O_DIRECT` within the program: I have no control on how Postgres reads the files
3. Mount my device using `-o sync`. I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/160185/turn-off-linux-file-cache) that it will turn off the write buffering but I am not sure if it disable reading from the cache as well?
4. Use `hdparm -W 0 /dev/sda1`: Again, this only disable the cache for writes.
5. Use an application specific script explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/242928/disable-linux-read-and-write-file-cache-on-partition): This would work if I had a single application, but in my setting, I have a Postgres server as a service (with many threads) and a client. I am not 100% sure but it seems like the script works for regular applications not the services such as Postgres.